# Tracing a GAC Registered COM+ C# dll

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I need to be able to diagnose a COM+ registered dll that is called from a third party's application via a plugin to that application.

I haven't been able to figure out how to get a config file with trace listeners configured for it.  As a matter of fact, (I do know how to configure tracelisteners.) I don't know where the config file would go to be used during dll activation.

I need a solution to see the System.Diagnostic Trace Messages for a dll that I don't control the activation of it.

Comment: You cannot rely on a .config file in a COM server.  It needs to be copied in the same directory as the EXE that uses your server, that's too brittle.  You can configure trace listeners in your code, it doesn't have to be done with a .config file.  The DefaultTraceListener squawks with OutputDebugString(), visible in any unmanaged debugger or DebugView.

Answer (score 0):

The SysInternals [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) tool solves this problem nicely.

I simply put the Trace.WriteLine statements in my dll code, and then they appeared in the DebugView output window.